# GraphPlots Julia - How to add node labels?

Tags: julia, data-visualization, ijulia-notebook

I am currently in the process of plotting a directed graphs using Julia. After some time on the internet I came across the GraphPLot package which seems to be doing an ok job.

However, I can't find out how to add node labels! Here is [my code and output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YrQrP.png) from the jupyter notebook.

Update: 
I tried the suggested method from GitHub

`nodelabel = [1:number_vertices(g)]
   gplot(g, nodelabel = nodelabel)`

But I get a weird error:

LoadError: Must have one label per node (or none)
while loading In[44], in expression starting on line 1

Comment: Your `nodelabel` has the wrong format. Try `nodelabel = 1:number_vertices(g)` or `nodelabel = [1:number_vertices(g);]`.

Comment: it turned out that, `nodelabel = collect(1:num_vertices(g))` worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing

```
nodelabel = [1:num_vertices(g)]
```

To `nodelabel = collect(1:num_vertices(g))` solves the issue.